# Error trying to connect to snapstore server

Tags: snap, snap-store

I need help with this here is the error can someone help

```
focal)keaton@localhost:~$ sudo snap install snapstore
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/snapstore: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```